# python difflib not calculating minimum difference

Tags: python, algorithm, difflib

I am using python's difflib to match non string sequences.

I have noticed that sometimes the results returned by difflib do not represent the minimum difference in the sequences provided.

In my application I have relatively short sequences that I need to match ( sequences of length under 100 elements) so the efficiency of the algorithm is not a problem, getting an optimal (maximum match length) result is very important though.

I assume I'm doing something wrong but I cannot figure out what.

Here's an example that works as it should:

```py
import difflib

s1 = [1,10, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4]
s2 = [2,12, 3, 5, 4, 6, 1]

def printMatchingBlocks(s1,s2):
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2,autojunk=False)
    for elm in matcher.get_matching_blocks():
        print( elm)

printMatchingBlocks(s1,s2)
```

Running this returns the correct answer:

```
Match(a=2, b=0, size=1)
Match(a=3, b=2, size=2)
Match(a=5, b=5, size=1)
Match(a=7, b=7, size=0)
```

which matches like so:

```
1 <--> _
10 <--> _
2 <--> 2
_ <--> 12
3 <--> 3
5 <--> 5
_ <--> 4
6 <--> 6
4 <--> _
_ <--> 1
```

however if I add to the test sequences two different number on position 4 (13 and 14 in the example):

```
s1 = [1,10, 2, 3, 13, 5, 6, 4]
s2 = [2,12, 3, 5, 14, 4, 6, 1]
```

The whole matching algorithm seems to break down.

The match returned is:

```
Match(a=0, b=7, size=1)
Match(a=8, b=8, size=0)
```

The result simply matches s1[0] to s2[7] i.e. the first element of s1 with the last element of s2. This is obviously not the best match since the previous match (of length 4) is still valid and longer than the returned match.

I have tried turning the autojunk detection off ( as in the code example) but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Any suggestions as to what might be causing the observed behaviour or how I could get the longest match  would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's your expected output? Do you need to find all matching blocks? Or do you only need a measure of similarity? Would swapping `s1` and `s2` be an acceptable solution to your problem?

Comment: I need to find the longest matching sub-sequence (not just the distance). Swapping s1 and s2 is acceptable. Trying your suggestion I see that swapping s2 with s1 does seem to return the longest sub-sequence. Any idea why ? Or how can I determine which is the 'proper' way to call given two sequences (short of calling it both ways and seeing which result is 'better').

Comment: I don't think the inner workings of the difflib library are specified or documented anywhere. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks) do say that _" The triples are monotonically increasing in i and j"_ however, so basically the `get_matching_blocks` function does something different than you want - it does _not_ search for the longest equal sequence. You will likely have to write your own code to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand what you are saying. I was hoping that the diff algorithm will provide the optimal solution (minimum edit operations to transform s1 to s2).  I understand that this is very expensive for long sequences and difflib is probably using heuristics to return a 'good enough solution' in a 'resonable' amount of time.